# Laravel и архитектура для Rest API

Tags: php, laravel, rest, архитектура

Доброго времени суток!

Пишу сервис на Laravel, в котором использую только API запросы.
Возникли некоторые вопросы, так как ранее использовал Laravel только с шаблонизатором.

### Стандарт ответа сервера

Есть 3 варианта возврата данных:

1. Простой успешный ответ `{"id": 33, "queue_number": 15, "user_name": "Alex"}`
2. Успешный ответ с пагинацией или простым списком `{"count": 100, "page": 10, "data": [[JSON object]...]}`
3. Ошибка(и) `{"errors": [["code": 1, message: "Undefined field(s)", fields: ["uid", "timestammp"]]]}`

У меня всего 12 видов ошибок. Я создал базовый класс `BaseRestException` и наследую от него каждый вид ошибки. Так вот, вопросы.

***Где на верхних уровнях отлавливать BaseRestException и приводить к третьему из описанных выше варианту возврата данных?***

Если я создаю для роута свой Request-класс и валидацию данных провожу внутри этого класса. ***Как в случае ошибок валидации мне вернуть ошибку в моем варианте возврата ошибок?***

Comment: Рекомендую разделить ваш вопрос на отдельные посты и запрашивать по ним, иначе это не будет соответствовать рекомендациям сообщества SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На Ларавел есть единая точка прихода Исключений `App\Exceptions\Handler.php`. В этом классе можно делать с исключениями что угодно.

Официальная документация: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/errors#the-exception-handler

**Вопрос похожий на Ваш с хорошим ответом и примером реализации:** 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51065170/laravel-api-how-to-properly-handle-errors

По поводу валидации, откройте базовый FormRequest там можно покопаться и найти методы отвечающие за валидацию.

**Примеры с обработкой валидации и кастомного ответа:**

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-make-a-custom-formrequest-error-response-in-laravel-55?page=1

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097371/laravel-validation-error-customise-format-of-the-response

Comment: что делать если не использую FormRequest?

Comment: @EvgeniiSh делайте кастомную валидацию, вырасываете исключение, а на нижем уровне отлавливаете.